# How to resolve Firebase AdMob Integration problem

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add AdMob ads to my Flutter app. For that, I tried using firebase_admob (^0.9.3+2) plugin but it's not working for me, it stuck at build.apk.
I am getting the output as :

```
Note: /home/abhishek/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admob-0.9.3+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseadmob/AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

My dependency in pubspec.yml are :

```
dependencies:

  flutter:
  sdk: flutter  
  meta: ^1.1.8  
  platform: ^2.2.1  
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9  
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2  
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+2
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's not an error, that's a note.

Comment: sorry i edited the question. Actually, when I run without debug, it stucks at building apk.

Comment: Then does it work on iOS?

Comment: i haven't tested it for ios, as my app is exclusive for Android.

Comment: There are various reason for the the build to stuck at the last step. You need to provide a complete log. Only then the exact problem will be found.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can remove `firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9` then exec `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is related or not, but I'm having problems adding dependencies:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'google_sign_in' in 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart'.
lib/authsvc.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart'
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
```

I'm able to add the dependency in the pubspec.yaml file, run 'pub get' and it says that it downloads fine. No errors are reported in the editor (i.e. it recognizes the new commands and doesn't flag them). However, when I try to compile/build it, I get the above error message. 'Pub get' worked fine until I upgraded to the latest version of Flutter (v. 1.17.3) before I believe I was on (v. 1.17.0).

To fix it, I hardcoded the path in the Dart_Packages.xml file.
(I'm not looking to troubleshoot further, just adding this in case it helps the developers identify the problem). Thanks!